# Problems with sqlite syntax

Tags: mysql, sqlite

Hi everyone I have a question about sqlite syntax, so I am aware it works similar to mysql, but when I try to modify two tables in sqlite it gives me error in the comma where you are 'users', 'score' to modify the two tables and mysql works normal with this syntax, which is what I am doing wrong to get this error someone can help me.

> SQL Error: near ",": syntax error

```
`UPDATE `users` , `score` SET `user`='usernew',`us_score`='usernew' WHERE `user` like 'userold' and `us_score` like 'userold'`
```

Comment: Please provide the structure of the tables (which field belongs to which table), and example of before/after data.

Comment: See https://sqlite.org/lang_update.html it describes SQL as understood by SQLite. There is no support of multiple tables being updated in one statement. I think the easiest way to port your code is to split it into two update statements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQLite does not understand update statements with more than one table name.

I.e. `UPDATE table1 , table2 ...`

See https://sqlite.org/lang_update.html it describes SQL as understood by SQLite.
There is no support of multiple tables being updated in one statement.

I think the easiest way to port your code is to split it into two update statements.

```
UPDATE table1 ... ;
UPDATE table2 ... ;
```

Comment: that's what I thought of the two table, just wanted to simplify it is sad to know that sqlite does not support multiple tables. thanks for the reply